# Web.config transform overwriting main web.config in TFS folder

Tags: asp.net, tfs, web.config-transform

Last month I set up web.config transforms for various configurations: local, dev, staging, production, etc.  When publishing, these all worked but now it seems that when I publish, it overwrites the current Web.config in the TFS source folder, and then copies that to the specified build folder.  What that means is that if there is an insert, it ends up creating duplicate items in those web.configs.  I've been hunting for a solution or reason to why this happened, but I can't find anything.  I haven't changed any setting in the project or in the transforms other than removing some of the duplicate tags in the main web.config.  Any ideas what might be causing this suddenly?

Comment: Do you use TFS build? Are you using XAML build or new tasks based build? How does your build definition look like?

Comment: Please post your build definition.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still getting the hang of build definitions, so not sure whether we use a task-based build or XAML build.  We are using continuous integration if that helps.  When I look at the build definition, I'm not seeing any reference to tasks, but only to Process Template, which I can provide here if needed (it's kind of long).

Comment: The other thing to note is that in the project build properties I set up something for a robots.txt file that works in the same way in that pre-build it copies a configuration-specific version (eg robots.staging.txt) of that file in a robots_txt subfolder into /robots.txt on the root: copy /y "$(ProjectDir)robots_txt\robots.$(ConfigurationName).txt" "$(ProjectDir)robots.txt"

Comment: It seems you are using XAML build. How do you publish your project? Log on to your build agent machine, and use MSBuild command line to build your project manually to see what result will you get. If the issue persists with MSBuild command line, you can share your steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after going through my project file line by line, I finally found this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Removing it solved the issue.  I have no idea how this snuck into the project file, but there you go!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using tasks based build, check your build definition to see whether you have tasks like "Replace Tokens" "Copy files", and check how you set the task.